# Django ImportError No module named 'catalog.context_processors'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-context

I'm a Django beginner and I encounter an issue with django context_processors.
I want use a queryset in all my template for generate a menu. 
But I get this error when I try to reach this page http://mysite/catalog which calls my cardabelle/catalog/views.py :

```
ImportError at /catalog/
No module named 'cardabelle.catalog'
```

Here "cardaballe" is my project name and "catalog" my application name.

Here is some interesting part (i guess) from my cardabelle/cardabelle/settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'catalog',
    'autoslug',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'template')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'cardabelle.catalog.context_processors.categories',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cardabelle.wsgi.application'
```

and here is my custom context in cardabelle/catalog/views.py :

```
def categories(request):
    return Category.objects.value()
```

Somebody knows why django doesn't find my new custom context ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have the file `context_processors.py` in the directory *catalog*, which is on the same level as the directory *cardabelle*?

```
/catalog
    __init__.py
    context_processors.py
    ...
/cardabelle
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    ...
```

If yes, the `context_processor` setting should read

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ...
                'catalog.context_processors.categories',
                # ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Also the context_processor should return a `dict`. Your current code reads `Category.objects.value()`. This is probably a typo while pasting it to SO? Just in case, make sure it reads `Category.objects.values()`, which returns a list of dicts.

```
def categories(request):
    return {'menu_categories': Category.objects.values()}
```

It will then be available as `{{ menu_categories }}` in your templates.